# Stripe creating two customers instead of one (Firestore and FlutterFlow)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, flutterflow

I'm trying like heck to get Stripe subscriptions working with Firebase in a web app. I added Stripe as an extension in Firebase but I'm having some issues here and there.

**What's working:**

- Stripe and Firestore can talk with each other, so when I log into my web app a user is created in Firestore and then a Stripe webhook updates that Firebase user's information to include a couple of pieces of data, like the `stripeId` and `stripeLink`. A Stripe customer is also created in Stripe.

Stripe Customers View:

[image: Stripe Customers view]

Firestore:
[image]

- When I create a subscription directly on Stripe's website, the user's information gets updated with the `payments` and `subscription` subcollections. This does not happen when I do this in the web app.
  [image]

**What's NOT working:**

- After the user logs in, goes to the payment page, and submits their payment, a new Stripe customer is created. That shouldn't be the case. It should use the already created customer.
  The bottom customer was already there. The top one was created after checkout.
  [image]
- When a payment is made, Firestore is not updated with the subscription that was paid for. (this is probably because of the previous problem where I have two customers created)
  Is there a way to let Stripe know to use the already existing customer during checkout as opposed to it making a new one after checkout has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'checkout' process you're referring to, is it using Stripe Checkout / Payment Links / Pricing Tables ?
If so, that might be why.

If you're using one of the following:
-Checkout in `subscription` mode.
-Payment Links / Pricing Tables with recurring items.
Then Stripe Checkout automatically creates a Customer for you.

-With Stripe Checkout, you can disable this by setting your own existing Customer with the `customer` argument:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#handling-existing-customers
-With Payment Links and Pricing Tables, there is no current way to do this.

Hope my hunch is correct about your checkout process or else this is pointless.

Comment: You are spot on with what I was trying to do. This definitely led me down a good path. I was able to do everything I needed to inside the API Explorer on the page. Now I need it to work in my app. I'm guessing I need to make a Cloud Function with the code they give and use the returned URL as the checkout page, that now has the customer attached to it. I just don't know how to fully do that yet.

Comment: Happy I could help. I’m not familiar with your framework so I can’t help you with the redirect, however what stripe recommends is a server redirect to the Session.url. A lot of people experience CORS issues when they try to pass the url down to the client for a front end redirect.

Comment: One addendum, for those it might apply to: you can tell Checkout to limit customers to one subscription, so providing a known email will direct them to manage that subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/limit-subscriptions